# Plotly r, line style by variable

Tags: r, r-plotly

I am trying to make a scatter plot where the line style is specified by a factor variable, just as one does with colors, but I can't get it to work.

```
library(plotly)
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(20),y=rnorm(20),col=c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10)),dash=c(1,2))
df <- df[order(df[,1]),]
plot_ly(data=df,x=~x,y=~y,type="scatter",mode="lines",color=~as.factor(col),line=list(dash=~as.factor(dash)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myselfes:

```
plot_ly(data=df,x=~x,y=~y,type="scatter",mode="lines",color=~as.factor(col),linetype=~as.factor(dash))
```

Comment: Please note that this runs into trouble if you have more than 6 levels in your factor. `plotly` is funny like that

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot.